# Locale link in Grails

Tags: grails, hyperlink

when I change locale in my project, a get a link like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/someapp/?lang=en
```

how i can get link in restful style, ex:

```
http://localhost:8080/someapp/en
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define in param **lang** in URLMapping, for example:

```
"/$lang?/contact_us"(controller: "pages", action: "contact_us")
```

Use **createLink** to generate links correctly.